# When i use nacos as nacos as discovery, open spring cloud config setting "spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true", application run fail

Tags: spring-cloud-config

When I use nacos as nacos as discovery, open spring cloud config setting "spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true", application run fail

```
my bootstrap.properties
spring.application.name=waiter-service


spring.cloud.nacos.discovery.server-addr=192.168.40.129:8848

spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=config-service
```

Application run error info : Caused by: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available`

Comment: application run error info :  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your spring cloud version lower than 2021. If your spring cloud version is higher than 2021. You shoule add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or you can use `application.yaml` to use nacos config:

```
server:
    port: {port}
spring:
    application:
        name: {app-name}
        nacos:
            discovery:
                server-addr: {host}:{port}
            config:
                server-addr: {host}:{port}
                group: {group}
    config:
        import:
            - optional:nacos:{config-name-version}
```

do not add `.properties` or `.yaml` in the end of `- optinal:nacos:{config-name-version}`